# Windows form wrong Resolution VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, resolution, dpi

When I start my application, here is the result :
[image]

I also tried to use metro gui, but nothing...

Also my question is, What option of visual studio should I setup to get the normal (not blurred) resolution of the winform?

Comment: have you tried setting the form's AutoScaleMode property to None?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because your application is not DPI aware and your display settings are not set to the default scaling

The easiest fix is probably to set `dpiAware` to `true` in the application manifest (`Project Properties>Application Tab>View Windows Settings Button`).

See this answer for details on this: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e)

For further details see this article [Why does a High DPI Setting Make My Application Look Fuzzy and Have Clipped Text?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/04/15/why-does-a-high-dpi-setting-make-my-application-look-fuzzy-and-have-clipped-text/)

Also see this article [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: OMG thx realllllllllllllllly

Comment: No problem at all - don't forget to upvote and accept when you can :-)

Comment: I don't understand where is the application manifest?

Comment: @adoloulreal - see my edit